# tinycthread Compilation error

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, tinycthread

I am now using tinycthread to do some thread programming. My compiler is Visual studio 2010. I got such error "Unreolved external symbol thrd_create" It seems i need some library to solve problems. I got no ideas what should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add two files to your project, tinycthread.c and tinycthread.h.